# Ubuntu not picking up Wifi Adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I booted Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my Pc using UsbImager and everything seemed fine.

When I went to Try Ubuntu before installing, the only problem was that wifi did not show up. Bluetooth did.

I have a TP LINK AC1300 Mini Wifi adapter plugged into my PC, as there is no internal wifi card.

I have checked several forums and the amazon Q&A and still cannot figure out if this product is compatible with Ubuntu.

Does anyone know if it is? If so, how do I get Ubuntu to pick up the adapter and get wifi running?

Appreciate the help in advance!

Comment: What is "UsbImager"?

Answer (score 0):

This particular WiFi device uses an Archer T4U chipset, which needs a special driver to operate. This needs to be compiled from source on your machine. Fortunately, it's not too difficult. Here's how:

0. Open Terminal (If it's not already open)
1. Install some prerequisites:

   ```
   $ sudo apt install git linux-headers-generic build-essential
   ```
2. Clone the Git repository to your Downloads directory (or any other, but Downloads is fine for this case):

   ```
   $ cd ~/Downloads
   $ git clone https://github.com/nyetwurk/linux-wifi-88x2bu-driver
   ```
3. Compile and install the driver:

   ```
   $ cd linux-wifi-88x2bu-driver
   $ make
   $ sudo make install
   $ sudo modprobe 88x2bu
   ```

At this point Ubuntu should pick up the WiFi device and let you connect to the network. If it does not, a reboot may be in order.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are very very appreciated, thank you Matiago. Just confirming because I am new to Linux. I just follow all three steps IN terminal, correct? When you mean downloads directory, I just have to type that line?

Comment: Hey Matigo! After the first one it says “package has no installation candidate” any idea why?

Comment: Typo. You should be good with the updated commands.

Comment: Will give it a shot. Also - how do I insert a line break within terminal? Do they have to be written out exactly as you displayed it?

Comment: The `$` means it's a new command. So `cd ~/Downloads`, hit [Enter]. Then `git clone ...` 

Comment: After the first command, it says do you want to continue and I said Y, but then it could not/failed to fetch all the archives, therefore could not do the second part. Any idea why?

Comment: It says E: unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apr-get update or try woth —fix-missing?